# How do I turn a Python string stored in a variable into a byte sequence?

Tags: python, string

Very simple, I know, but the docs aren't too helpful. I'm trying to hash a simple string. I was following [this](http://pythoncentral.org/hashing-strings-with-python/) guide. The example given therein is:

```
import hashlib
hash_object = hashlib.md5(b'Hello World')
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
```

And then you have a hash representation. Suppose I want to take this one step further. I have four strings I want to concatenate together, the result of which needs to be converted to byte sequence, in order to be passed to the `hashlib.md5()` function. However, I'm curious how I can replicate the `b'Hello World'` syntax using a variable instead of a hard-coded string. Docs seem to suggest you can pass in a format to the built-in [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) function, so for my use-case something like:

```
my_string = '%s%s%s%s' % (first, second, third, fourth)
byte_string = format(my_string, 'b')
```

This doesn't quite work, though. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in Python are a sequence of characters, to convert a string to a sequence of bytes you encode it using some character set.  For example:

```
my_string = '%s%s%s%s' % (first, second, third, fourth)
byte_string = my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

Instead of `my_string.encode('utf-8')` you could also use `bytes(my_string, 'utf-8')`, these are equivalent.  You can also use a different encoding if you like, but UTF-8 is generally a good choice because it is capable of representing any code point (character) and it is fairly compact, especially for ASCII data.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string = '%s%s%s' % (first, second, third, fourth)
byte_string = bytes(my_string)
```

Comment: ahh true ... i just copied from OP :P